# Split fancybox title and get first few letters from it and change color

Tags: jquery, fancybox, title

Below is my fancybox code

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({           
        arrows : true,
        openEffect : 'elastic',
        closeEffect : 'elastic',
        loop: false,            
        width: winWid,
        height: winHi,
        fitToView: true,

        helpers : {
            title: {
                type: 'inside',
                position: 'top'
            }
        }           
    });
```

I have given filename as title so I am getting title like

```
folder/someimage.jpg
```

I am showing this title at top of my fancybox, here what I need is to change the color of foldername not filename, like

```
folder(red color)/someimage.jpg(normal black color)
```

Any help

Comment: whoever down voted it please share your thoughts, why you did so? what is wrong with this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `afterLoad` callback to re-compose the `title`.

You first need to `split()` the `title` by the slash `/` and wrap the *folder* part in a `span` element like :

```
var tFolder = "<span class='red'>" + this.title.split("/")[0] + "</span>";
```

Then add a CSS rule to set the color to the *class* of the `span` element like :

```
.red {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

Last, re-compose the `title` joining the folder part with the second part (the image name) like :

```
this.title = tFolder + "/" + this.title.split("/")[1];
```

The full code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        // API options
        helpers: {
            title: {
                type: 'inside',
                position: 'top'
            }
        },
        afterLoad: function () {
            var tFolder = "<span class='red'>" + this.title.split("/")[0] + "</span>";
            this.title = tFolder + "/" + this.title.split("/")[1];
        }
    }); // fancybox
}); // ready
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mezp8gh0/1)**